# Reverse engineering an existing database with flywaydb?

Tags: flyway

can flywaydb support this processing?

1. Setup a reference Oracle database outside of flyway.
2. Create some testdata within this reference database using an application.
3. Reverse engineer this database with flyway.
4. Create test databases during automated builds with flyway based on Scripts gathered through Point 3.

I know that 1,2 and 4 are possible. But what's with Point 3?

Answer (score 3):

No, flyway does only support forward db migrations and no reverse engineering of database. If the database is created outside of flyway then flyway does not even have any information on current state of database schema.

Unfortunately to reverse engineer a database you have to use other tools.