# Reverse Engineer an Oracle Database with Flyway

Tags: oracle, flyway

Is it possible to reverse engineer an oracle database using flyway?

I need to dump all the schema's from a database, including all objects, but don't need the data.

I found this, but it's from 4 years ago

[Reverse engineering an existing database with flywaydb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179990/reverse-engineering-an-existing-database-with-flywaydb)

Could someone confirm if that's still the case and you can't reverse engineer an oracle database with flyway?

Thanks

Comment: What you need is this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL200. It will allow you to export schemas, objects, tablespaces and what not. It creates a .dmp file, which can then be imported somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks @g00dy I did look at this, but I don't want any data, or a dump file, just sql files to create a baseline.  I can accomplish creating a DDL with other tools, just wondering if flyway was capable of doing it these days.

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) can achieve this. You can find the feature in Tools/Database Export menu. [Here is the docs page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/impexp.htm#BABJIFDA).